# node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member named 'IMinimatch'. Did you mean 'Minimatch'?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have rimraf as a devDependency (v5.0.0). When I try to run a script using rimraf it gives me this error:

```
node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:29:42 - error TS2694: Namespace '".../node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'.
29     interface IOptions extends minimatch.IOptions {
                                            ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:74:30 - error TS2724: '"...node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member named 'IMinimatch'. Did you mean 'Minimatch'?

74         minimatch: minimatch.IMinimatch;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:29
```

I manually removed the `node_modules/@types/glob` folder and the error is gone, rimraf works perfectly. The problem is that I don't have glob or minimatch or its types as dependencies on my project, so I'm not able to remove the dependency to solve the issue.

These are the dependencies that I have in my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@open-wc/building-rollup": "2.0.1",
    "@open-wc/eslint-config": "7.0.0",
    "@open-wc/testing": "3.1.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "4.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.20.0",
    "@web/dev-server": "0.1.30",
    "@web/test-runner": "0.13.27",
    "@web/test-runner-puppeteer": "0.10.5",
    "concurrently": "7.1.0",
    "deepmerge": "4.2.2",
    "eslint": "8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "husky": "7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "12.4.0",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "rimraf": "5.0.0",
    "rollup": "2.70.2",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "3.4.0",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "typescript": "4.6.3"
  }
```

I don't know if it's just rimraf that is causing the issue, or could be another one.

Appreciate the answers! :)

Answer (score 5):

I resolved similar issue just forcing to override `glob` and `minimatch` package. Maybe its not the right solution, but I saw many nested packages using differents versions for `minimatch` and `glob` so my first try was use the latest packages.

**STEPS**

**1- I added at the end of ***package.json*** the next**

```
 ... 
 "overrides": {
    "minimatch": "5.1.2",
    "glob": "8.1.0"
  },
 ...
```

**2- After add to the package.json, I just need to prune:**

> npm prune

**Optional:** In case that dont work try to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

> rm -rf node_modules; rm package-lock.json

and install again all modules/packages

> npm install

**Here the full example if you want to see where to add inside your package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "expressjs/express",
    "mocha": "mochajs/mocha#4727d357ea",
    "module": "user/repo#feature/branch"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "minimatch": "5.1.2",
    "glob": "8.1.0"
  }
}
```

[NPM Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json)

Answer (score 4):

If i had to guess, it looks like one of your dependencies is having an issue with the version.

I would try deleting the package.json and reinstalling.

You can also read more about your particular issue here:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/63967

EDIT: after some more research, I found that the `@types` packages for these specific dependencies might be causing the issue. Try removing them.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved!

In my case it was an `open-wc` dependency which was causing the issue.

`@open-wc/building-utils` had an outdated version of `minimatch`.

To resolve the issue I just added the `"@open-wc/building-utils": "2.0.1"` to my package.json and forced an updated version.

Comment: This is great :D You unblocked me!

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this same issue by upgrading the minimatch package to [version 3.0.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/minimatch/v/3.0.3)